# Listview of Stopwatch timespans - how to continue timers in UI

Tags: listview, xamarin, timer, countdown

I have a listview of activities, each containing a timespan which is pulled in from my MongoDB collection. On tapped of an activity listview item, I start my stopwatch, addition the current timespan to the elapsed time and this works fine. However the only problem is, is that the timer doesn't continue to run in the UI, the timespan is only updated to the UI on each tap.

Could you please advise on how I should go about the continued running of individual timers based on each activity tapped? See my listview and Tapped Event method below:

Listview

```
 <ListView
                     x:Name="ActivitiesList"
                     SelectionMode="None"
                     CachingStrategy="RetainElement"
                     HasUnevenRows="True"                     
                     BackgroundColor="White"                    
                     IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding UserActivitiesList }"
                     RefreshCommand="{Binding getUserActivities}"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"                    
                     SeparatorVisibility="None"
                     RowHeight="70"                      
                    >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell
                                Height="60" Tapped="OnActivityTap"
                             > 
                                
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="activitiesGrid"
                                          HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="600" Margin="20,0,20,0" >

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                                                                                
                                            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>                                           
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/> 
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/> 
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                       <Label
                                            Grid.Row="0"                                                          
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                                            FontAttributes="None"                                       
                                            Text="{Binding ActivityName}"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                            TextColor="Black"                                            
                                            Padding="0,10,0,0"
                                            FontFamily="Hiragino Sans"
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            HeightRequest="53"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                       />
                                        <Label
                                            Grid.Row="0"                                                          
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            FontAttributes="None"                                       
                                            Text="{Binding ActivityDuration}"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            Margin="0, 0,0, 0"
                                            Padding="0,10,0,0"
                                            FontFamily="Hiragino Sans"
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            HeightRequest="53"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                       />
                                        <Label
                                            Grid.Row="0"                                                          
                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            FontAttributes="None"                                       
                                            Text="{Binding ActivityGoalDuration}"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            Margin="0, 0,0, 0"
                                            Padding="10,10,0,0"
                                            FontFamily="Hiragino Sans"
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            HeightRequest="53"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                       />                                        
                                         <Switch
                                            Grid.Row="0"                                                          
                                            Grid.Column="3"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"                                                                                                                            
                                            HeightRequest="53"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                            IsToggled="{Binding ActivityEnabled}"
                                            Toggled="activitySwitch_Toggled"
                                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                       />
                                    </Grid>

                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Event

```
 public void OnActivityTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (ViewCell)sender;
            UserActivities.Activities myactivitiesModel = item.BindingContext as 
            UserActivities.Activities;

            if (myactivitiesModel == null)
            {return;}
            foreach (var x in ViewModel.UserActivitiesList) {
                if(x.ActivityName == myactivitiesModel.ActivityName) {
                    mystopwatch.Start();
                    TimeSpan ts = myactivitiesModel.ActivityDuration;
                    ts = mystopwatch.Elapsed + ts;
                    x.ActivityDuration = mystopwatch.Elapsed + ts;
                }
}
```

Comment: Stopwatch is intended for use as a debugging tool.  User System.Timers.Timer instead.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your help, but I'm not able to get the elapsed time with timer - I tried: TimeSpan ts = myactivitiesModel.ActivityDuration;
                    myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
                    TimeSpan test = myTimer.Elapsed.ToString;
                    x.ActivityDuration += myTimer.ToString(); but I get the error that elapsed can only appear on left side... any help on this??

Comment: create a property for elapsed_time and update it on every timer tick

Comment: Sorry, can you show an example solution as I'm still new to this...

Comment: @Avatar I'm not sure what this sentence means **However the only problem is, is that the timer doesn't continue to run in the UI, the timespan is only updated to the UI on each tap**, you want to update **ActivityDuration** value or others?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thank you for your help, yes I'd like to update ActivityDuration in UI continuously however it only updates on tap, can you show me how to do this with either countdown or timer, I don't mind because it doesnt seem possible to get the elapsed time with timer...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question as follows:

```
                    //Create a new stopwatch
                    mystopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                    
                    //Add the current duration
                    TimeSpan ts = mystopwatch.Elapsed + x.ActivityDuration;

                    //Start stopwatch
                    mystopwatch.Start();

                    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds), () =>
                    {                        
                        x.ActivityDuration = (mystopwatch.Elapsed + ts);
                        OnPropertyChanged("ActivityDuration");
                        return true;
                    }
                    );
```